# How to setup two Google Storage Buckets for a Django application, one for MEDIA files and the other for STATIC files?

Tags: python, django, gcloud

Here is the error I am getting at the home page of my app.

```
Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.
```

```
#settings.py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage

try:
    # Load service account info from environment variables
    service_account_info = {
        "type": env("TYPE"),
        "project_id": env("PROJECT_ID"),
        "private_key_id": env("PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        "private_key": env("PRIVATE_KEY"), 
        "client_email": env("CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        "client_id": env("CLIENT_ID"),
        "auth_uri": env("AUTH_URI"),
        "token_uri": env("TOKEN_URI"),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": env("AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        "client_x509_cert_url": env("CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL")
    }
    # Create credentials from the service account info
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info=service_account_info)
    
    # Initialize the Google Cloud Storage client with your credentials
    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=env("PROJECT_ID"))

    # List all buckets -> this works 
    buckets = list(client.list_buckets())
    print("Buckets in {}:".format(client.project))
    print(buckets)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error initializing Google Cloud credentials: ", e)
```

```
#also settings.py

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'fly_io_test.gcloud.GoogleCloudMediaFileStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"

GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = env("DEV_STATIC_FILES_BUCKET_NAME")
GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = env("DEV_MEDIA_FILES_BUCKET_NAME")

STATIC_URL = f"https://storage.googleapis.com/{GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME}/admin/"    
MEDIA_URL = f"https://storage.googleapis.com/{GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME}/"
```

I have have run `gcloud auth login` , `gcloud config set project <project_id>.`  and then `gcloud auth application-default-login`  in the container seemingly successfully.

1. I'm getting the ADC error
2. I don't know if this will write media files to the MEDIA bucket and STATIC files to the static bucket.

### Update

I'm not sure why they would provide the from_service_account_info method if it runs into this ADC issue, as the same information is passed, just in a different way. Please let me know if there is something I'm not appreciating.

Anyway, the below seems to work now. The gcloud CLI (I assume?) was looking for an environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that contains the file path to a json file containing the service account information.

Doing it in the below way allows you to keep sensitive service account information outside of source control and allows you to have a single file you might upload with all of your apps configuration etc.

```py
try:
    # Load service account info from environment variables
    service_account_info = {
        "type": env("TYPE"),
        "project_id": env("PROJECT_ID"),
        "private_key_id": env("PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        "private_key": env("PRIVATE_KEY").replace("\\n", "\n"),
        "client_email": env("CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        "client_id": env("CLIENT_ID"),
        "auth_uri": env("AUTH_URI"),
        "token_uri": env("TOKEN_URI"),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": env("AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        "client_x509_cert_url": env("CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL")
    }

    # Convert the service account info to JSON and write it to a temporary file
    with open('/tmp/service_account.json', 'w') as temp_json_file:
        json.dump(service_account_info, temp_json_file)

    # Point GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the temporary file
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/tmp/service_account.json'

    # Now you can initialize the Google client library
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        '/tmp/service_account.json'
    )
    
    # Initialize the Google Cloud Storage client with your credentials
    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=env("PROJECT_ID"))

    # # List all buckets # WORKS
    # buckets = list(client.list_buckets())
    # print("Buckets in {}:".format(client.project))
    # print(buckets)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error initializing Google Cloud credentials: ", e)
```